# Capistrano fails deployment without stopping process first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am having this issue with capistrano when i issue:

> cap deploy

```
     ** [out :: ***] rake aborted!
     ** [out :: ***] Killed
     ** [out :: ***] 
     ** [out :: ***] (in /home/deployer/apps/webapp/releases/20130203054234/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.3.0/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
     ** [out :: ***] 
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
     ** [out :: ***] 
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
     ** [out :: ***] /home/deployer/apps/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:74:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     ** [out :: ***] 
     ** [out :: ***] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:nondigest
     ** [out :: ***] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

However when I stop the process first and then deploy, everything works fine.  ANyone else experiencing the same issue?

> cap deploy:stop
>
> cap deploy

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, had to add the following to the gemfile:

```
# for the assets group
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

Hope it helps anyone else.